VB.Net Session Variable Shorthand
Just wanted to share a little shorthand function that I came up with to make session variables a little less un-weildy.  The problem:
Session("NameOfSomething","Bob")
Label1.Text = Session("NameOfSomething")
Session.Remove("NameOfSomething")

The Solution:
s("NameOfSomething","Bob")
Label1.Text = s("NameOfSomething")
sr("NameOfSomething")


Code is read more often than it's written. I can look at the top code sample and immediately know what it's doing. If I'm just presented the second code sample, I now need to go and investigate how it's working. That may work okay for you as a sole developer but it's not a good habit to get into in general.

Fair enough, and you're right: it's only practical for a small-ish team that's all aware of it.  As soon as you have a larger team and any significant turnover in developers, it would be a problem.  Since it's just me working on my stuff, I've come to like the shorthand of it, but your point is quite valid.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

In looking at the problem statement, I find the "NameOfSomething" part a lot more unwieldy than Session or Session.Remove, both of which are likely to be typed as one or two characters then a tab thanks to IntelliSense.  Your suggestion does nothing to help with that.

Well no, variable naming is still whatever you make it-- good or bad.  "ses" brings up the IntelliSense which it quick enough but then you still need to do the ".re"  that's where the "sr" is nice.  But like Damien said above, it's not great if you have others working on the same code. But for my little solo stuff, it's something that I use constantly which is why I wanted to shorten it in the first place.

and VS has inteli-sense, right. So, you type in se, and 9 out of 10 times, you get session, and thus once again, I see VERY little value here. And in 99% of cases, you can go Session("NameOfSomething") = "bob". So, even the System..Web.HttpContext.Current is VERY RARE required, since by default such web pages (code behind) will have that imported reference automatic for you anyway.  So, we did not save typing, we only really reduced readability and maintainability.  Not clear at all why Session("somevalue") is not being used here in place of System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session()?

Yeah, so as you can see, I stashed that in its own module so it's easy to find but for the most part I never look at it again after I copy/paste it into a new project.  As for the reason it has the full System.Web.HttpContext.Current, I seem to remember that it sometimes produced errors or just didn't work without it being very explicitly assigned.  I call this function from all over the code (Modules/Classes/Code-behind) and it just works anywhere I use it.  I'm a self-taught (Google) amature programmer so I really don't know a lot of the ins/outs/theory, just that it works for me.

Well, that's the issue then: > "I seem to remember" that sometimes it produced an error! - that reason should be determined! - the reason is that a given page class (code behind) can use Session(), but code outside of the page will need the full reference. However, in such cases, you would be MUCH better to pass the Session() object to that library code (class or module). Hence, once again , we are back to did we really save developer time and hassle here?  Code outside of the page (class, or module) thus REALLY should require passing the Session() object, and not assume a global session().

So I guess I'm just wondering why it would be MUCH better to pass the Session() object to each class or module as opposed to a simple, easy to find function that can be used globally.  I totally get that it would be problematic if this was a team project but, on a single-developer project,  are there performance/stability considerations regarding global functions that I may not be aware of?   I'm really just trying to learn at this point so I appreciate the stackoverflow feature to ask/answer own question to begin a discussion.

It's better in many (not all) to pass the session object, since stand alone code modules are not part of the page class (code behind for a given page).  Thus, such code is more modular, more re-useable, and such general code thus has reduced dependance on Session(). In fact, in most cases, if you have say 4-5 variables/values in session, then best to create a new type, or even a class, and then pass that object/type to those other routines. That way, those routines are not actually dependent on Session(), and can be re-used in other projects, even non web ones.

In other words, Session() being global is already a bad idea, since over time, what happens if other code you call just so happens to use the same session() value? This makes software VERY difficult to follow and maintain. If you pass a "set" of values to those routines (as a type or class), then you can not only have multiple instances of those variables, and not be constrained to global session().  I mean, what happens if some routine outside of the page you call uses session(), but then all of a sudden you have two pages open, and they both used that same session() value?

In other words, by directly NOT using session() in those general code modules, then such code can be re-used and called from other pages, and other bits of code, since global = the general code routines are not so general anymore with hard coded global values. We don't say declare some "i" variable to be global, since then our for i = 1 to 10 loops will get messed up (the instant you call some other code in a for/next), since i would be global, and that is a bad idea. Same goes for your general code routines - pass the value(s), and not have session() strewn all over the place in such code.

I guess I need to look into this further.  I didn't think it possible to have two pages open within the same session which it why I've been using them for everything that isn't specific to a particular instance of a Sub/Function but might be needed in multiple Subs/Functions.  Mostly the way I use them is for things like role/permission handling.  In my DB, I have a table of allowed permissions by role.  Then when any role is activated, it selects each permission and assigns each session variable T/F so that for instance, role "Admin" can see the page "Edit User" but the role "User" cannot.

How it's accomplished:
Module SesVars    
    Public Function s(ByVal SesVarName As String, Optional ByVal SesVal As String = Nothing)
        If SesVal IsNot Nothing Then System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("" & SesVarName & "") = SesVal
        If System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("" & SesVarName & "") Is Nothing Then s = Nothing : Exit Function
        s = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("" & SesVarName & "")
    End Function
    Public Sub sr(ByVal SesVarName)
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("" & SesVarName & "")
    End Sub   
End Module

